# How to Prevent Direct Access to a php file that is generating Image

Tags: php, image

I have a php file that is generqating Image and that is being included in the image tag like this:

```
<img src"generate_contact.php?memberid=3456">
```

Now if anyone will try to access this file directly, with a memberid query string, they an actually see the image file being generated.

**How can i prevent direct access to** `"generate_contact.php"`?

Note: If i try to make a CONSTANT in the file in which this img tag is inserted, will generate_contact.php have access to that CONSTANT? asking because generate_contact.php is not being included.. it is being added as src in image tag only.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean "can see the image being generated"? By putting this into an img src URL, people *are* having to access it "directly", otherwise they couldn't see the image.

Comment: Means: if i access it like http://mysites.com/generate_contact.php?memberid=3456 they will be able to see the image directly and then spammers can hack it and populate contacts.. the image i am generating is of Contact ids of the user

Comment: That question has been answered many many times on SO and not only.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an incremental member-id to access this image, why not using a unique hash?

In your members table, add a "hash" field, and add a random string inside this field for each member.

I'm used to generate 10 chars hash this way :

```
$hash = substr(str_shuffle(base_convert(str_shuffle(sha1(str_shuffle(md5(rand() . microtime())))), 16, 36)), 0, 10);
```

After that, use your hash to identify your member :

```
<img src = "generate_contact.php?memberhash=0qxv(...)"/>
```

In such a way, crawlers will not be able to increment the id and get associate contact of your whole members.

Comment: This makes it hard for people to guess the members id to get to the image.

Comment: That seems a secure way to do.. I will try this.. thank you buddy

Comment: @user This is *obfuscation*, not *security*. Obfuscation can be useful to simply make it hard to automatically scrape all images. If you need actual **security**, you need to make authorization checks before outputting the image.

Comment: @Ninsuo the method you are using will always generate unique key?

Comment: What kind of authentication you would suggest? @deceze  .. any example?

Comment: You have 1 chance of 36^10 = 3656158440062976 to get the same hash for 2 members. You should check if it exists when creating it. (if you have a collision, play loto :))

Comment: I can only assume what you need, but assuming only a particular user is allowed to see a specific image, I'll assume you already have a session based login system, so in that case just check if the current user is allowed to see the image in `generate_contact.php` or not.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to prevent direct access to an image that you're wanting to display to the user. By having:

```
<img src = "generate_contact.php?memberid=3456">
```

You're already giving them direct access because the user's browser will actually make a GET request for the file once the page has loaded. Trying to prevent direct access to an image that you're wanting to display to the user goes against the fundamentals of the Internet, in which users request public documents.

Answer (score 0):

The users browser making a request for image to be placed inside the page is a 'get' request, and is same as if you type the address directly. There is no way you can actually place an image on a page and then keep it unaccessible completely, unless ofcourse using flash

Answer (score 0):

OK, take it back one step.

It's all about URLs. If you put a URL into an image element's src attribute, the image must be available at that URL:

```
<img src="/img/profile/42.jpg">
```

The browser will download the HTML document with this image element, then make *another HTTP request*, just like the first one, to that URL to also download the image.

You can put that URL directly into your browser's address bar for the same effect. There's certain content available at some URL. It does not matter how that URL is accessed. It is not "tied to an HTML document" or "secret" or "hidden" or anything like that because it's in an HTML document.

**URLs are always public and accessed "directly", otherwise nobody could see their content.**

So, either your URL `generate_contact.php?memberid=3456` spits out an image or it doesn't. What it does behind the scenes is irrelevant.

Comment: Can't you check the referer or something like that?

Comment: @marvin You *can*, but that's hardly any protection. If the OP is worried about "hackers", a referer check is a laughable "defense".

Comment: Oh, I thought it was the page/url that included the img tag and he could prevent it if it wasn't what he expected.